# Android. Can i read resource xml as String? in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

Im looking for something like this.

```
String mainActivityLayoutAsString = ReadResourceAsString(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

No.  The layout files aren't kept as raw XML.  They're preprocessed to a form easier to parse at runtime.

Comment: it indeed only works for `raw` resources ...as the name might already suggest.

Comment: So there is no possible way to access it? at all?

Comment: @uzu Nope, its just not in there.